# Complete database reset for MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This may seem like a very dumb question but I didn't learn it in any other way and I just want to have some clarification.

I started to use MySQL a while ago and in order to test various scenarios, I back up my databases. I used MySQL dump for that:

Export:

> mysqldump -hSERVER -uUSER -pPASSWORD --all-databases > filename.sql

Import:

> mysql -hSERVER -uUSER -pPASSWORD < filename.sql

Easy enough and it worked quite well up until now, when I noticed a little problem with this "setup": It does not fully "reset" the databases and tables. If, for example, there is an additional table added AFTER a dump file has been created, that additional table will not disappear if you import the same dump file. It essentially only "corrects" tables already there and recreates any databaes or tables missing, but does not remove any additional tables, which happen to have names that are not in the dump file.

What I want to do is to completely reset all the databases on a server when I import such a dump file. What would be the best solution? Is there a special import function reserved for that purpose or do I have to delete the databases myself first? Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Deleting data without backup is never a god idea.

Comment: AFAIK, imports from SQL files will not delete data, unless the SQL file contains DELETE/DROP queries.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the parameter --add-drop-database to add a "drop database" statement to the dump before each "create database" statement.

e.g.

> mysqldump -hSERVER -uUSER -pPASSWORD --all-databases --add-drop-database >filename.sql

see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about the dump and restore processes you describe.  `mysqldump` writes out SQL statements that describe the current state of the database or databases you are dumping. It has to fetch a list of tables in each database you're dumping, then it has to read the tables one by one and write them out as SQL. On databases of any size, this takes time.

So, if you create a new table while `mysqldump` is running, it may not pick up that new table. Similarly, if your application software changes contents of tables while `mysqldump` is running, those changes may or may not show up in the backup.

You can look at the .sql files `mysqldump` writes out to see what they have picked up.  If you want to be sure that your dumped .sql files are perfect, you need to run `mysqldump` on a quiet server -- one where nobody is running data definition language.

MySQL hot backup solutions are available. You may need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The OP may want look into

```
mysql_install_db
```

if they want a fresh start with the post-install default
settings before restoring one or more dumped DBs.  For
production servers, another useful script is:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Also, they may prefer to dump the DB(s) they created separately:

```
mysqldump -hSERVER -uUSER -pPASSWORD --database foo > foo.sql
```

to avoid inadvertently changing the internal DBs:
mysql, information_schema, performance_schema.